# Why this function and property, present inside of controller is NOT being accessed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**`app2.js`**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("panel",[]);
    app.controller('PanelController',function(){
          this.tab = 1;

          this.setTab = function(setTab){
                this.tab = setTab;
          };


    });

})();
```

And the **`view`** is:

```
<html ng-app="panel">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>\
    <style type="text/css">
    li{
        width:100px;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" >
        <li ng-class="{active:tab === 1}"><a ng-click="panel.setTab(1)" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab === 2}"><a ng-click="tab = 2" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab === 3}"><a ng-click="tab = 3" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab === 4}"><a ng-click="tab = 4" href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>{{tab}}</h1>

    <div class="panel">
        <p ng-show="tab===1">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 1 </p>
        <p ng-show="tab===2">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 2 </p>
        <p ng-show="tab===3">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 3 </p>
        <p ng-show="tab===4">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 4 </p>

    </div>



</section>



</body>
</html>
```

Problem is with `panel.set(1)` which is not being invoked when `<a>` is clicked. Why is it so? Neither the property `tab` inside of controller is being accessed.

Comment: instead of definint `tab` as a property of `this`, you need to use `$scope.tab`

Comment: @gefei Can you elaborate what's the difference between the two? Why should I use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`panel.setTab` is invoked. The problem is caused by the `tab` variable in the template. You should replace them with `panel.tab`.

`<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">` means that

```
$scope.panel = new PanelController();
```

so if you want to use variable inside your controller. You should add `panel.` prefix, otherwise it means `$scope.tab`

Comment: This is a nice explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you are using controllerAs syntax you also need to use it when you set/check active tab. So basically you need to use `panel.tab` instead of just `tab` (which is `$scope` property, rather than controller own field).

So your fixed code will look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(1)}">
        <a ng-click="panel.setTab(1)" href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(2)}">
        <a ng-click="panel.setTab(2)" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(3)}">
        <a ng-click="panel.setTab(3)" href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(4)}">
        <a ng-click="panel.setTab(4)" href="#">4</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<h1>{{panel.tab}}</h1>

<div class="panel">
    <p ng-show="panel.tab===1">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 1 </p>
    <p ng-show="panel.tab===2">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 2 </p>
    <p ng-show="panel.tab===3">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 3 </p>
    <p ng-show="panel.tab===4">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 4 </p>
</div>
```

Where I also defined convenient `isActive` method so your template looks cleaner:

```
this.isActive = function(tab) {
    return this.tab === tab;
};
```

Here is working demo of the solution.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('PanelController', function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;
    };

    this.isActive = function(tab) {
        return this.tab === tab;
    };

});
```

```css
li {width: 100px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="demo" ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(1)}">
            <a ng-click="panel.setTab(1)" href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(2)}">
            <a ng-click="panel.setTab(2)" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(3)}">
            <a ng-click="panel.setTab(3)" href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: panel.isActive(4)}">
            <a ng-click="panel.setTab(4)" href="#">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>{{tab}}</h1>
    <div class="panel">
        <p ng-show="panel.tab===1">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 1 </p>
        <p ng-show="panel.tab===2">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 2 </p>
        <p ng-show="panel.tab===3">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 3 </p>
        <p ng-show="panel.tab===4">Suppose this is Data coming from object for 4 </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("panel",[]);
    app.controller('PanelController',function($scope){
          $scope.tab = 1;

          $scope.setTab = function(setTab){
                $scope.tab = setTab;
          };

    });
})();
```

and

```
 <li ng-class="{active:tab === 1}"><a ng-click="setTab(1)" href="#">1</a></li>
```

Comment: It works. Would be great if you can add some explanation or link to some related article in the answer.

Comment: This is not very good solution because instead of best practice `controllerAs` usage it reverts to better-to-avoid scope syntax.