# Controller property not being show in view in this Angular js app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below is `aap.js` from my AngularJS app.

```
var app = angular.module('gallery',[]);

(function(){

    app.controller('GalleryController',function(){
        this.tab = true;
    }); 
})();
```

`and gallery.html` is:

```
<html ng-app="gallery">

<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">    
</head>
<body ng-contoller="GalleryController as g">
 <section >
 <ul>
     <li><img ng-click="tab=1" src="images/gem-01.jpg" height="100" /></li>
 </ul>
     <h1>{{g.tab}}</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

`g.tab`, which is a property of controller, is not being shown in view. Why is that so?

Comment: $scope does the 2 way binding between controller and view. So you need to set things on $scope and not on this for binding to work.

Comment: @brute_force Can't this be done with using `this`? Like this example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679215/4904589

Comment: Yes this can be used. From 1.2.0 onwards it can be used.
Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940503/1235298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT AGAIN: I miss read your issue. You are using the `this` keyword correct however the `tab` property is not being shown when you click the image because the `ng-click` is using `tab` not `g.tab`. See updated updated updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8uby8oz/2/

<s>You cannot use the `this` keyword within your controllers like that. The context of your controller method is not your scope.</s> Yes you can see edit.

You can use that syntax withing services but not controllers, instead your scope is injected in along with other services, factories etc.

Instead it should be

```
app.controller('GalleryController',function($scope){
    $scope.tab = true;
});
```

Most likely overkill but added fiddle to demonstrate anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/z8uby8oz/

EDIT: This can be achieved using the `this` keyword. I didn't know this learn something new everyday. That is by using the `as` operator in your `ng-controller`.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8uby8oz/1/
And docs i found it in: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example

My understanding is the `as` operator binds your scope to a property in your view that you pass `test as myScope` means bind the `this` keyword of your `test` controller the the `myScope` property in your view.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Can't this be done with using `this`? Like this example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679215/4904589

Answer (score 0):

you bind all the values to $scope

```
var app = angular.module('gallery',[]);

    (function(){

        app.controller('GalleryController',function($scope){
            $scope.tab = true;
        }); 
    })();
```

your **HTML** looks like

```
<html ng-app="gallery">

<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">    
</head>
<body ng-contoller="GalleryController">
 <section >
 <ul>
     <li><img ng-click="tab=1" src="images/gem-01.jpg" height="100" /></li>
 </ul>
     <h1>{{tab}}</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't this be done with using `this`? Like this example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679215/4904589

Comment: $scope is the variable which transfer values between controller and views. You can bind multiple objects in $scope. you can't be achieved by simply this.